# Develop android application manager from scratch

Tags: android, google-api, development-environment

I want to make an application manager like `Google Play` that allows user to download `APK` file to her/his mobile phone and update any application when there is a new version.

So I need information how to start first step, how to notify the application if there is a new update is there `Google API` allow me to download `APK` file directly to the application server and update to the last version?

Any help information what I should use and shall not use are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could check every x minutes or when Internet connection appears if there is new version of Your application on server. You could also use Google Cloud Messaging to notify users that update appears.